# Newbie in .net: how to add a library to project

Tags: .net, import

I'm new in .net and I'm interesting in following.
I've downloaded a library from [this](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx.).

But I don't know how to import it into my project for using.

How do I do that?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the solution Explorer, select your project, then click Add Reference and select the assembly.

You can also simply add it to the project BIN folder.

Comment: And be prepared to wait a couple minutes for the damn dialog to load!!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a DLL to your project, right-click it in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, and click 'Add Reference', then select 'Browse' and locate your DLL.

Answer (score 1):

right on your project > add Reference > tab named "Brows" and you specify the dlls to import.

Caution : It's only a reference, the library file is not imported/moved in the Solution directory. So if you want to move/send your solution you should probably create a subdirectory in your solution (it's often called "libs"), add the dll inside and then add the reference.

\MySolution

...................\Libs\YourLibrary.dll

....................\YourProject...

The libs directory is a Windows directory on the file system but also a solution folder in Visual Studio (right click on the solution, add a solution folder)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(VS.80).aspx